# array_search acting unpredictably

Tags: php

I have a simple function that looks at an incoming mySQL data type and then rolls it up to a "category" (called a family in this code) so that I can apply default values at the category level. Anyway, this code works fine for finding integer, character, and text categories but completely fails on datetime and decimal categories. I'm at my wits end. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
public static function get_family_type ( $col_type ) {
    $families = array (
                'integer' => array ( 'integer', 'int', 'tinyint', 'mediumint', 'bigint' ),
                'fixed' => array ( 'decimal', 'numeric' ),
                'floating' => array ( 'float' , 'double' ),
                'character' => array ( 'char', 'varchar' ),
                'datetime' => array ( 'datetime' , 'timestamp'),
                'time' => array ('time'),
                'date' => array ('year'),
                'text' => array ('tinytext', 'text', 'mediumtext' , 'longtext'),
                'blob' => array ('blob','tinyblob','mediumblob','longblob')
    );

    // first get rid of any optional length parameterisation
    list ( $col_type ) = explode ( "(" , $col_type , 2 );
    foreach ($families as $family => $family_members) {
        if ( array_search ( $col_type , $family_members , true ) ) {
            return $family;
        }
    }
    return "unknown $col_type";
}
```

note the backup return statement on the last line and then look at this output from a table I've defined elsewhere in code.

```
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of integer
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of text
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of integer
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of integer
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of unknown decimal
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of character
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of unknown datetime
    [18-Jun-2012 17:39:24] Getting default for family of floating
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_search](http://www.php.net/array_search) returns the array key on success, and that will sometimes be the value of 0. In php, 0 coerces to boolean false. You need to check like

```
    if ( array_search ( $col_type , $family_members , true ) !== false ) {
        return $family;
    }
```

Note the strict comparsion `!==`

the php manual mentions this in the documentation for array_search.

Comment: Why is it better then just use in_array(), which return boolean itself? Willn't it be less resource consuming?

Comment: actually, in_array() is a better way to do it. But, I was trying more to explain why it was failing in its current form.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was thinking about in_array over breakfast before I read this and I guess you've both confirmed that this is the better technique. Thanks to Rambo I can do it with either function now.

Answer (score 2):

Thy change:

```
if ( array_search ( $col_type , $family_members , true ) ) {
            return $family;
    }
```

to

```
if ( in_array( $col_type , $family_members , true ) ) {
            return $family;
   }
```

Note, that:

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
>   corresponding key if successful

So, it's not boolean return from array_search, that possibly why it works not as you wish.